# portable windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WinForms Different DPI Layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850915/winforms-different-dpi-layouts)

I have made an application which uses high number of pictureboxes in a windows form. I have successfully completed the project. But my problem started when i deployed the application onto my friends laptop which has a smaller display screen. Not all pictureboxes and controls were visible. i.e. some controls went out-of form and were inaccessable.

Actually I had developed the application on my desktop which has larger display screen. How do I make the form portable so that inspite of display screen variation, the controls are correctly displayed?

I know it is a simple problem of Normalized co-ordinates...But I dont want to sit down and plan the co-ordinates (like : Screen 1unit length and 1 unit breadth. So 1st conrtol at 0.25,0.3 position) coz it will waste my time as the application has vast pictureboxes and controls.

Isnt there a tool in Visual studio which will automatically use normalized co-ordinates and maintain it in the deploy file so that it is portable?????

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296810/how-can-i-make-my-winforms-application-dpi-aware , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850915/winforms-different-dpi-layouts  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196606/net-2-0-winform-supporting-dpi-and-default-font-changes

Comment: @Magnus: so just vote to close it ...

Comment: @genesis, which I did. The comment is only to highlight other questions.

Comment: You don't want to do any work: just set the form's AutoScroll property to True.  Friends' response: "works, but that's kinda lame dude!".  Allow the window to be resized at will, that fixes the resolution problem too.  It's not that hard.

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool. Its called WPF. It has [device independant graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373.aspx#visual_rendering_behavior) which renders the same, regardless of the size.

Other then that, you will have to manually normalize it yourself

Comment: the guy seems to me is talking about WinForms

Comment: Surprising how poorly this problem is understood.  WPF doesn't fix it either, you can cram a Window full of controls too.

Answer (score 3):

use [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) and position your controls within the cells of the table, which will care on resizing

use **Anchor/Docking** property of controls for correct *relative* alignment.

Regards.

Comment: TableLayoutPanel will only help control the position of things. It won't affect the size at all

Comment: actually the post talks about positioning of controls and not resizing of them

Comment: from msdn : "The TableLayoutPanel control arranges its contents in a grid. Because the layout is performed both at design time and run time, it can change dynamically as the application environment changes. This gives the controls in the panel the ability to proportionally resize, so it can respond to changes such as the parent control resizing or text length changing due to localization."                                                         http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using a [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9e8s203.aspx) with the `AutoSize` property enabled? You can build it so its dynamically sized at runtime.